# Plot bars being shifted to the right when painting between two unrelated lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a bar chart with some horizontal lines. The lines represent the baseline and standard deviation.

If I comment the `fill between` line, the bars are centered in each unit. Otherwise, they are right-aligned. Am I doing something wrong? How do I fix this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Agents},
        width=0.28\textwidth,
        height=0.25\textwidth,
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.5},
        ybar=0pt,
        bar width=0.25,
        xtick={1.5,2.5,...,9.5},
        xticklabels={2,...,9},
        x tick label as interval,
        xmin=5, xmax=9,
        ymax=140
    ]

    \addplot[draw=black,smooth,dashed] coordinates {(4.5,111)(9.5,111)};
    \addplot[name path=black_top,smooth,color=black!50] coordinates {(4.5,136)(9.5,136)};
    \addplot[name path=black_down,smooth,color=black!50] coordinates {(4.5,86)(9.5,86)};
    \addplot[black!20,fill opacity=0.2] fill between [of=black_top and black_down]; % THIS LINE BREAKS THE BARS

    \addplot+[color=black,fill=green,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit] coordinates {( 5 ,  94.87666666666667 )+-(0, 23.40752294959781 )( 6 ,  80.05466666666666 )+-(0, 21.522437276457225 )( 7 ,  64.15666666666667 )+-(0, 16.67690645011687 )( 8 ,  60.133 )+-(0, 18.43625402583517 )( 9 ,  50.91766666666666 )+-(0, 16.16000343323637 ) };
    \addplot+[color=black,fill=yellow,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit] coordinates {( 5 ,  95.51833333333333 )+-(0, 23.22793158057708 )( 6 ,  84.58733333333333 )+-(0, 23.009232926050753 )( 7 ,  75.2744488977956 )+-(0, 26.206436774916398 )( 8 ,  58.797 )+-(0, 15.941772440729855 )( 9 ,  53.17666666666667 )+-(0, 14.808804487817241 ) };
    \addplot+[color=black,fill=red,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit] coordinates {( 5 ,  94.84100000000001 )+-(0, 22.82644169743311 )( 6 ,  78.558 )+-(0, 18.713503938615418 )( 7 ,  68.35833333333333 )+-(0, 16.593949039798076 )( 8 ,  63.76233333333332 )+-(0, 16.30226192649106 )( 9 ,  57.321333333333335 )+-(0, 15.308328400611293 ) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a bug or a feature, but you can draw the plot what you want also without the `fillbetween` library. See the following code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.11,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Agents},
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.5},
        ybar=0pt,
        bar width=0.25,
        xtick={1.5,2.5,...,9.5},
        xticklabels={2,...,9},
        x tick label as interval,
        xmin=5, xmax=9,
        ymax=140,
        error bars/y dir=both,
        error bars/y explicit,
    ]

        \path [draw=black!50,fill=black!20,fill opacity=0.2]
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},86)
                rectangle
                    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},136);
        \addplot [draw=black,smooth,dashed] coordinates {(4.5,111)(9.5,111)};

        \addplot [fill=green] coordinates {
            ( 5 ,  94.87666666666667  )+-(0, 23.40752294959781 )
            ( 6 ,  80.05466666666666  )+-(0, 21.522437276457225 )
            ( 7 ,  64.15666666666667  )+-(0, 16.67690645011687 )
            ( 8 ,  60.133             )+-(0, 18.43625402583517 )
            ( 9 ,  50.91766666666666  )+-(0, 16.16000343323637 )
        };
        \addplot [fill=yellow] coordinates {
            ( 5 ,  95.51833333333333  )+-(0, 23.22793158057708 )
            ( 6 ,  84.58733333333333  )+-(0, 23.009232926050753 )
            ( 7 ,  75.2744488977956   )+-(0, 26.206436774916398 )
            ( 8 ,  58.797             )+-(0, 15.941772440729855 )
            ( 9 ,  53.17666666666667  )+-(0, 14.808804487817241 )
        };
        \addplot [fill=red] coordinates {
            ( 5 ,  94.84100000000001  )+-(0, 22.82644169743311 )
            ( 6 ,  78.558             )+-(0, 18.713503938615418 )
            ( 7 ,  68.35833333333333  )+-(0, 16.593949039798076 )
            ( 8 ,  63.76233333333332  )+-(0, 16.30226192649106 )
            ( 9 ,  57.321333333333335 )+-(0, 15.308328400611293 )
        };

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]